# Equation in the field

Tags: field-theory

For which n the equation $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$ has roots in the field of $3^n$ elements?

I don't have any ideas of how the equation's roots depend on the field's elements. Does the number of elements $3^n$ means that we consider the equation modulo $3^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means the "Galois field" of order $3^n$. This is isomorphic
to $\Bbb F_3[X]/\left<f(x)\right>$ where $f$ is any irreducible degree
$n$ polynomial over $\Bbb F_3$. Anyway the roots of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$
are the primitive fifth roots of unity. A field of order $3^n$ has primitive fifth roots of unity iff $5\mid(3^n-1)$. This is because
$3^n-1$ is the order of the multiplicative group of the field.